# SQL Fulltext Search Index or custom query to searching app database?

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have a .NET, SQL2005, C# website which will be open to public in June 2011
Site has video albums containing videos. Video albums and Videos has title, tags, description and other fields.

Video albums and videos are stored in different tables. Video albums can be public and private. **I want to exclude the private albums and videos from search**

I have stored procedure that searches just the tag field of albums and videos tables.

Will this stored proc scale with the number of rows in the tables?

I don't have full text search on title or tag field.

I would prefer searching the Title field. But the query requires '%keys%' format which slow.

What do you recommend to go with as search solution and prevent redesign later on?

**EDIT: My original question was longer and nobody cared. So shorted.**

Answer (score 0):

You might look into Google Site Search. It's easy, customizable, and recognizable.